# Loop through two directories and access the files outside the loop

Tags: r, loops, raster

I want to loop through two directories simultaneously. Both directories contain raster-images, one the initial images the other one the masks for these images.

I would like to access them outside the loops since I have to do some calculations but also keep my folder structures.

The loops don't have to be nested in each other, I guess, but how can I access the files outside the loop? Creating an empty stack/raster outside and fill it with the values from the stack/raster of the loops does not seem to the trick.

So far I got this:

```
library(raster)

files1 = list.files(path2, pattern = "*.tif", full.names = TRUE)
files2 = list.files(path4, pattern = "*_cmask.tif", full.names = TRUE)
f1Stack = stack()
for (f1 in files1) {
    f1Stack = stack(f1)
         do stuff with f1Stack
    for (f2 in files2) {
        f2Raster = raster(f2)
        do stuff with f2Raster
    }
 }
```

edit:
I want to store the Raster Stack created inside the loop to be accessible outside. files1 contains 10 multiband-tiffs. If I create an empty stack outside the loop try to update it with the current stack in the loop, it always contains just the last stack of the loop.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be a bit more specific on what exactly you're trying to achieve (what do you want to do with the rasters?) and if possible add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would want to start this way:

```
library(raster)
files1 <- list.files(path2, pattern = "\\.tif$", full.names = TRUE)
files2 <- list.files(path4, pattern = "_cmask\\.tif$", full.names = TRUE)
s1 <- lapply(files1, brick)
s2 <- lapply(files2, brick)
```

That is, create a list of RasterBrick objects (more efficient that RasterStack) of each file. Than you can manipulate each object in the list (loop or another lapply), and you won't loose them.

Comment: Thank you! Was not aware of this simply solution using lapply.